# mockgen not generating mock for interface

Tags: go, go-modules, gomock

Project structure

- `~/vscodego` - has `go.mod` and `go.sum` and one `.go` file
- `~/vscodego/testfiles` has `heap1_test.go     test1_file_test.go`

Under the directory `~vscodego/testfiles`, trying to generate mock for interface that is in the file `heap1_test.go`

Command and error as below

```
princes-MBP:testfiles prince$ mockgen --build_flags=--mod=mod . MyStructIntf 
vscodego/testfiles: no non-test Go files in /Users/prince/vscodego/testfiles
vscodego/testfiles: no non-test Go files in /Users/prince/vscodego/testfiles
go: finding module for package go.uber.org/mock/mockgen/model
prog.go:14:2: package vscodego/testfiles is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.20.5/libexec/src/vscodego/testfiles)
2023/07/07 17:11:32 Loading input failed: exit status 1
princes-MBP:testfiles prince$
```

Contents of the test file `heap1_test.go`

```
package testfiles

import "testing"

type MyStruct struct {
    age  int
    Name string
}

func (m *MyStruct) getName() string {
    return m.Name
}

type MyStructIntf interface {
    getName() string
}

func TestHeap1(t *testing.T) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

mockgen needs two arguments, an import path, and a symbol/symbols.

include the import path as `<your_module_name>/testfiles`

```
mockgen --build_flags=--mod=mod <your_module_name>/testfiles MyStructIntf
```

Comment: What would that be in above case? Did some reading but it says something about go.mod wrt module.

Comment: it is module from go.mod e.g. if in go mod `module ab.com/usr/mdl`, module name is `ab.com/usr/mdl`